# Vertical Navigation wont show on every page - Magento

Tags: magento, navigation

i am having trouble with my vertical navigation. I want it to show on every single page.

I used [this guide to make the vertical navigation](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/4_-_themes_and_template_customization/navigation/how_to_create_a_vertical_left_hand_menu)

this is [my website](http://www.theshirt.org)

I am new to magento and web developement also.

Thanks Guys